# Event handler being subscribed multiple times

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm a WPF newb, so go easy on me.

I have a button that is using dependency properties in order to make use of the mouse leave event, and this part works just fine on it's own. Here is the code that does this...

```
// ==================================
// Mouse Leave Behavior
public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseLeaveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "MouseLeave", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MouseBehaviors), new PropertyMetadata(null, MouseLeaveChanged));

public static ICommand GetMouseLeave(DependencyObject obj) {
    return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(MouseLeaveProperty);
}

public static void SetMouseLeave(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value) {
    obj.SetValue(MouseLeaveProperty, value);
}

private static void MouseLeaveChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    UIElement uiElement = obj as UIElement;

    if (uiElement != null)
        uiElement.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(uiElement_MouseLeave);
}

static void uiElement_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    UIElement uiElement = sender as UIElement;
    if (uiElement != null) {
        ICommand command = GetMouseLeave(uiElement);
        if (command != null)
            command.Execute(uiElement);
    }
}
```

And the xaml of the button:

```
<Button x:Uid="btnNoDBConnInfo" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Background="Silver" Margin="2,0,0,0" Width="22" Height="22"
        Command="{Binding NoDBConnInfoCmd, Mode=OneWay}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsSacadaConnected, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
        attProps:MouseBehaviors.MouseEnter="{Binding MouseEnterDatabaseImgCmd}"
        attProps:MouseBehaviors.MouseLeave="{Binding MouseLeaveDatabaseImgCmd}">
    <Image Source="/MDCT;component/Images/database--exclamation.png" Stretch="None" />
</Button>
```

I also have some code that I dug up on the internet that basically displays a modal Dialog on top of whatever your current form is. There's way too much of this code for me to put in this question, but in a nutshell it creates a new Dialog control and then sets the parent controls content to the Dialog. I can't get too much more specific than this because I don't fully understand how it works. I know it won't help much, but here is the method that shows the Dialog.

```
public void ShowDialog(DialogBaseControl dialog)
{
    _layerStack.Add(_parent.Content);
    _parent.Content = dialog;
}
```

**The problem that I am experiencing is this:** The MouseLeaveChanged static method gets called a second time whenever a Dialog control is set to the Content property of the parent (ie - when the very last line of code shown above gets executed). So what ends up happening is the MouseLeave event gets registered (subscribed??) a second time to the button. The same thing happens for a third time when the Dialog control gets closed. What do I need to change in order to stop the MouseLeaveChanged method from firing again when the Dialog control is shown/closed? Or is the solution to somehow remove the MouseLeave event from the button when the MouseLeaveChanged fires a second time?

I did some debugging in the MouseLeaveChanged method and noticed that the event args (DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) change each time that the method is called.

When the form is initially loaded and the MouseLeaveChanged method fires, debugging e.NewValue yields this:
{MDCT.RelayCommand}
    _canExecute: null
    _execute: {Method = {Void b__1(System.Object)}}

Debugging e.OldValue yields null.

However, when the Dialog control is shown and the MouseLeaveChanged method fires again, debugging the aforementioned values shows that they are swapped. In other words, e.NewValue yields null and e.OldValue yields the MDCT.RelayCommand. Presumably this would indicate that the registered mouse leave event should be unsubscribed (uiElement.MouseLeave -= ?????) at this time?

Comment: Perhaps the **Call Stack** might be useful here?

Comment: @Frank J - Forgive my confusion, but how is it a matter of event bubbling? Is the MouseLeaveChanged an event? In any case, I don't know understand what triggers the MouseLeaveChanged to fire.

Comment: @MikeEason - The first time that MouseLeaveChanged is fired, the call stack doesn't display anything but the MouseLeaveChanged itself, and just below that it says "External Code". The second time that MouseLeaveChanged fires (when the Dialog control is displayed) it displays the same, but just below the "External Code" it says Technewlogic.WpfDialogManagement.dll!Technewlogic.WpfDialogManagement.DialogLayeringHelper.ShowDialog

Comment: I see what you are saying, sorry I misread your code. I'll remove my first comment. As far as I can see, if `MouseLeaveDatabaseImgCmd` changes that would trigger a second call. One thing you could do is unsubscribe with `-=` right before you do the `+=` but that fixes the symptom not the cause and is no answer to your question.